# How to create a MySQL table where all columns are NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, null

I'm creating a table where I have no use for the NULL value. Therefore, all my columns are NOT NULL. This is how I create it:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  column1 TEXT NOT NULL,
  column2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  column3 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ...
```

Do I really have to write NOT NULL all the time? Or is there a way to prevent NULL columns to be inserted (by mistake)?

Comment: What is wrong with writing `NOT NULL` for each column?  How many columns do you have?

Comment: Yes, you have to.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I guess not so many, 10 or a bit more. But if I could by default prevent it, it would be nicer, since I won't use it anyway

Comment: @Mil0r OK, Thanks! Just making sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing SQL specification does not support **NOT NULL** for a  complete table. See [Specification](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp).
Even   MySQL 5.5 documentation  clearly states that **NOT NULL** can be applied to  column. So it can not be applied to  table.